# I want to generate two expandable sections with 4 rows and 2 rows .The following code generates two expandable section with 4 rows each

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c

In the following example section 1 and 2 expandable.But every expandable section has 4 cells each .I need a way to fit 4 rows in section 1 and 2 rows in section 2.The first method specifies the rows to be expanded and the rest are tableview delegate and datasource methods

```
 - (BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView canCollapseSection:(NSInteger)section
    {
        if (section>0 && section<3) return YES;

        return NO;
    }

    - (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
    {
        // Return the number of sections.
        return 4;
    }





- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{

    if ([self tableView:tableView canCollapseSection:section])
    {

        if ([expandedSections containsIndex:section])
        {

            NSLog(@"section number:%d",section);
            return 3; // return rows when expanded

        }
            return 1; // only top row showing

    }

    // Return the number of rows in the section.
    return 1;


}



- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }

    // Configure the cell...

    if ([self tableView:tableView canCollapseSection:indexPath.section])
    {
        if (!indexPath.row)
        {
            // first row
            cell.textLabel.text = @"Expandable"; // only top row showing

            if ([expandedSections containsIndex:indexPath.section])
            {
            //some code
            }
            else
            {
                //some code
            }
        }
        else
        {
            // all other rows
            cell.textLabel.text = @"Some Detail";
            cell.accessoryView = nil;
            cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        cell.accessoryView = nil;
        cell.textLabel.text = @"Normal Cell";

    }

    return cell;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Return proper number of rows in numberOfRowsInSection method

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    if ([self tableView:tableView canCollapseSection:section])
    {
        if ([expandedSections containsIndex:section])
        {
            NSLog(@"section number:%d",section);
            // -------------- UPDATE HERE --------------
            return (indexPath.section == 1 ? 4 : 2); // return rows when expanded
        }
        return 1; // only top row showing
    }
    // Return the number of rows in the section.
    return 1;
}
```